# Time expiration data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

On a recent coding interview I was asked to implement a key - value store data structure.
implement

size() : Number of elements in the list.

find(key) : Return the value at the key, otherwise throw nosuchelement exception.

insert(key, timestamp) : Add or update the element with this key. If the list is full, then don't do anything.

- The list has a maximum number of elements that it can hold
- Every element is inserted as a key and a value, time duration after which it should not be considered as in the list, and the time stamp of the time it was entered.
- If the list is full, then ignore the element trying to be added, unless it is a duplicate key.
- If the element with the same key already exists, update the existing value and the existing time stamp
- Once the time exceeds the time stamp + duration of an element, then don't consider it to be part of the structure any more. This means that if the list was previously full, It is not full any more.

I was having trouble finding an efficient way to keep track of the elements that are still in the list considering that elements can be ejected from the list if their time has run out.

Comment: You could either schedule a kind of timer task which ejects the items from the list when they expire, or you can eject them on every interaction wirh the list. For example: `public int size() { ejectExpiredElements(); return map.size(); }`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is an indexed priority queue. Basically, you build a min priority queue whose key is the timestamp. And you create an index (by key) that keeps track of item locations in the priority queue.

On every operation, you can remove expired items from the queue with something like:

```
while (pq.peek().timestamp < current_time) {
    pq.remove();
}
```

The complexity of that will be O(k log n), where k is the number of items you remove, and n is the total number of items in the queue.

There is an indexed priority queue implementation available at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html. I've heard good things about it, but I've never used it myself.

Comment: If you use a balanced binary search tree as a priority queue, it seems like you should be able to delete the elements with expired timestamps in O(log n) time instead of O(k log n) time where k is the number of expired elements. I'm not 100% sure about it, though, because rebalancing the tree is harder if you're deleting more than one node at a time.

Comment: An important detail to add to this.  Things go into the queue when they are inserted/updated.  When things come out of the queue you should verify that the timestamp was not updated before you delete them from the lookup.  (Note, I implemented a data structure much like this at my last job to query for relatively static information only once every few seconds rather than every time it was wanted.  It was a significant performance win.)

Comment: @kaya3 Even in a balanced binary tree, It requires O(log n) for each deletion. So if you're going to delete k items, it will take O(k log n).

Comment: Why delete them one at a time? You can delete half of the nodes in O(1) time by just setting root.left = null. It should take only O(log n) time to walk one branch of the tree and delete the left subtrees of the appropriate nodes. The problem is how to efficiently rebalance it when you delete a whole subtree at once.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, you can delete k nodes in O(k). But then, as you say, you have to re-balance the tree. Perhaps the complexity is better than O(k log n). But the code is quite a bit more involved. I'm not convinced that it will be faster than a heap when running on actual hardware.

Comment: I think it would be faster to just insert iterators to the element in the hashmap into a queue, and then before every action, you just pop the top of the queue until the top most element has a timestamp hasn't been exceeded.

Comment: @mk3009hppw And what do you do about insertion? Your idea assumes that you have a  list sorted by timestamp. So insertion will be an O(n) operation. You still need a keyed lookup, and you'll have update the indexes for every key that gets moved when you delete an item. And since deleting from the head of the list will move every item, you'll be updating every key for every item deleted. You can optimize that, of course, but you still end up having do do (n-k) updates, where n is the total number of items in the list, and k is the number of items you're deleting.